# how can i put delay in PHP mailer for sending mass emails

Tags: php, linux, cron, centos, phpmailer

I have the limit that i cant send more than 5 emails per second.

I am using PHPMailer 5.2.6

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/

Is there any way i can put 1 sec delay after 5 emails

I am  using sendmail in PHP script and use cron job to send emails

Comment: Do you really need something specific to PHPMailer? Can't you just use PHP's `sleep` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sleep(1) in your loop to put 1 sec delay